# How to work with binary contraints in linear optimization?

Tags: r, optimization, constraint

I have two input matrices, **dt(10,3)** & **wt(3,3)**, that i need to use to find the optimal decision matrix (same dimension), **Par(10,3)** so as to maximize an objective function. Below R code would give some direction into the problem (used Sample inputs here) -

```
#Input Matrices
dt <- matrix(runif(300),100,3)
wt <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1),3,3) #weights

#objective function
Obj <- function(Par) {
       P = matrix(Par, nrow = 10, byrow=F) # Reshape
       X = t((dt%*%wt)[,1])%*%P[,1]
       Y = t((dt%*%wt)[,2])%*%P[,2]
       Z = t((dt%*%wt)[,3])%*%P[,3]
       as.numeric(X+Y+Z) #maximize
       }
```

Now I am struggling to apply the following constraints to the problem :

```
1) Matrix, Par can only have binary values (0 or 1)
2) rowSums(Par) = 1 (Basically a row can only have 1 in one of the three columns) 
3) colSums(Par[,1]) <= 5, colSums(Par[,2]) <= 6, & colSums(Par[,3]) <= 4
4) X/(X+Y+Z) < 0.35, & Y/(X+Y+Z) < 0.4 (X,Y,Z are defined in the objective function)
```

I tried coding the constraints in constrOptim, but not sure how to input binary & integer constraints. I am reading up on lpSolve, but not able to figure out. Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `lpSolve` package can solve your question. `lp(direction, objective.in, const.mat, const.dir, const.rhs)` optimizes `objective.in %*% param` under `const.mat %*% param`. Your objective function is equivalent to `c(dt %*% wt) %*% Par`, so `c(dt %*% wt)` is the `objective.in` (I named it `f.obj`). 
(1) `lp(..., all.bin=T)` can solve it.
(2) It is equivalent to `cbind(diag(10), diag(10), diag(10)) %*% Par = matrix(1, nrow=10)`
(3) It  equialent to `diag(3)[,rep(c(1,2,3), each=10)] %*% Par <= matrix(c(5,6,4), ncol=1)`
(4) In your example, `X+Y+Z` is clearly `> 0`, so I supposed that `X+Y+Z > 0`. The former constraint `X/(X+Y+Z) < 0.35` can be rearranged to `-0.65*X + 0.35*Y + 0.35*Z > 0`. So, it is equivalent to `c(-0.65 * f.obj[1:10], 0.35 * f.obj[11:20], 0.35 * f.obj[21:30]) %*% Par > 0`. The latter can be processed in the same way.
To wrap up, below `f.con` can expresses all constraints.

```
library(lpSolve)

set.seed(1); dt <- matrix(runif(30),10, 3)
wt <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1),3,3) #weights

f.obj <- c(dt%*%wt)
f.con <- rbind(cbind(diag(10), diag(10), diag(10)),         # constraint (2)
               diag(3)[,rep(c(1,2,3), each=10)],            # constraint (3)
               f.obj * rep(c(-0.65, 0.35, 0.35), each=10),  # constraint (4-1)
               f.obj * rep(c(0.4, -0.6, 0.4), each=10))     # constraint (4-2)
f.dir <- c(rep("=", 10), rep("<=", 3), ">", ">")
f.rhs <- c(rep(1, 10), 5, 6, 4, 0, 0)

res <- lp("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs, all.bin=T)
Par <- res$solution

P <- matrix(Par, nrow=10)
P
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    1
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1
# [4,]    1    0    0
# [5,]    0    1    0
# [6,]    1    0    0
# [7,]    1    0    0
# [8,]    0    1    0
# [9,]    0    0    1
#[10,]    0    0    1
```

check the assumptions

```
X = t((dt%*%wt)[,1])%*%P[,1]
Y = t((dt%*%wt)[,2])%*%P[,2]
Z = t((dt%*%wt)[,3])%*%P[,3]

rowSums(P)   # [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
colSums(P)   # [1] 4 2 4
X/(X+Y+Z)    # [1,] 0.3307523
Y/(X+Y+Z)    # [1,] 0.3731207   # no problem
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Appreciate your time. I was able to solve this exactly the way you have transcribed using lpSolve :)

Comment: @Rohit If this answered your question, please accept the answer. See[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)